# How to write Unit test for Android ViewModel with SavedStateHandle

Tags: android

In Android ViewModel, how can I write unit tests to verify that the savedStateHandle is saving and restoring values correctly?

```
class SampleViewModel(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
    var foo: Int = 0 // In the actual code, foo is a non-parcelable type

    init {
        savedStateHandle.get<Int>("foo")?.let {
            foo = it
        }

        savedStateHandle.setSavedStateProvider("foo") {
            bundleOf("foo" to foo)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to create a SavedStateHandle, you can create and pass it in your Unit test like so:

```kotlin
val savedStateHandle = SavedStateHandle()
// or actually pass data with:
// SavedStateHandle(mapOf("foo" to 0))

val viewModel = SampleViewModel(
    savedStateHandle = savedStateHandle
)
```

Then, you can simply check if the value was set by calling

```kotlin
assert(savedStateHandle.get<Int>("foo") == 0)
```